# Flutter : Tried to automatically register plugins with FlutterEngine but could not find and invoke the GeneratedPluginRegistrant

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Getting this warning, when trying to run the Flutter application in Nougat (else it's working in all other versions), my application gets frozen at the Splash screen.

```
Tried to automatically register plugins with FlutterEngine (io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@cf8c995) but could not find and invoke the GeneratedPluginRegistrant.
```

I have commented code in
**MainActivity.java**, getting an error ***cannot find symbol*** after uncomment it

```
package com.orsac.bluis;

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
//  @Override
//  public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
//    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
//  }
}
```

Created another class
**UniappAplication.java** and trying to initialize  ***GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);*** getting error ***cannot find symbol***

```
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService;

public class UniappApplication extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
        FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this code with

```
// GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);
io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
```

Comment: `registry.registrarFor` deprecated